# 'Convert to CSV' plugin for HighCharts does not recognize all options for a chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, highcharts

I am trying to convert my Highchart into a `.csv` file. I am using the [Export chart Data to CSV](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export-CSV) plugin for the same. I have pasted the full code at the bottom of the question.

I try to run my code with the above file in scope and it does not have any effect. On further investigation I find out two things

1. the `getOptions()` method does not seem to be standard for the Highcharts library as there is no documentation for it.
2. It does not return the exhaustive list of options available for my Highchart. Hence, the

   `if (Highcharts.getOptions().exporting)`

at the end of the two functions (`getDataRows()` and `getCSV()`) returns `undefined`as it does not recognize `exporting`. What seems to be the problem here?

```js
/**
 * A small plugin for getting the CSV of a rendered chart
 */
/*global Highcharts, document */
(function (Highcharts) {

    'use strict';

    var each = Highcharts.each,
        downloadAttrSupported = document.createElement('a').download !== undefined;


    /**
     * Get the data rows as a two dimensional array
     */
    Highcharts.Chart.prototype.getDataRows = function () {
        var csv,
            options = (this.options.exporting || {}).csv || {},
            xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
            rows = {},
            rowArr = [],
            dataRows,
            names = [],
            i,
            x,

        // Options
            dateFormat = options.dateFormat || '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';

        // Loop the series and index values
        i = 0;
        each(this.series, function (series) {
            if (series.options.includeInCSVExport !== false) {
                names.push(series.name);
                each(series.points, function (point) {
                    if (!rows[point.x]) {
                        rows[point.x] = [];
                    }
                    rows[point.x].x = point.x;

                    // Pies, funnels etc. use point name in X row
                    if (!series.xAxis) {
                        rows[point.x].name = point.name;
                    }

                    rows[point.x][i] = point.y;
                });
                i += 1;
            }
        });

        // Make a sortable array
        for (x in rows) {
            if (rows.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                rowArr.push(rows[x]);
            }
        }
        // Sort it by X values
        rowArr.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.x - b.x;
        });

        // Add header row
        dataRows = [[xAxis.isDatetimeAxis ? 'DateTime' : 'Category'].concat(names)];

        // Transform the rows to CSV
        each(rowArr, function (row, i) {

            // Add the X/date/category
            row.unshift(row.name || (xAxis.isDatetimeAxis ? Highcharts.dateFormat(dateFormat, row.x) : xAxis.categories ? Highcharts.pick(xAxis.categories[row.x], row.x) : row.x));
            dataRows.push(row);
        });

        return dataRows;
    };

    /**
     * Get a CSV string
     */
    Highcharts.Chart.prototype.getCSV = function () {
        var csv = '',
            rows = this.getDataRows(),
            options = (this.options.exporting || {}).csv || {},
            itemDelimiter = options.itemDelimiter || ';', // use ';' for direct import to Excel
            lineDelimiter = options.lineDelimiter || '\n'; // '\n' isn't working with the js csv data extraction

        // Transform the rows to CSV
        each(rows, function (row, i) {

            // Add the values
            csv += row.join(itemDelimiter);

            // Add the line delimiter
            if (i < rows.length - 1) {
                csv += lineDelimiter;
            }
        });
        return csv;
    };

    /**
     * Build a HTML table with the data
     * /
     Highcharts.Chart.prototype.getTable = function () {
        var html = '<table>',
            rows = this.getDataRows(),
            options = (this.options.exporting || {}).csv || {};
        // Transform the rows to HTML
        each(rows, function (row, i) {
            var tag = i ? 'td' : 'th';
            html += '<tr><' + tag + '>';
            // Add the cells
            html += row.join('</' + tag + '><' + tag + '>');
            html += '</' + tag + '></tr>';

        });
        html += '</table>';
        return html;
    };
     */

    // Add "Download CSV" to the exporting menu. Use download attribute if supported, else
    // run a simple PHP script that returns a file. The source code for the PHP script can be viewed at
    // https://raw.github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/master/studies/csv-export/csv.php
    if (Highcharts.getOptions().exporting) {
        Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
            text: Highcharts.getOptions().lang.downloadCSV || 'Download CSV',
            onclick: function () {
                var a;

                // Download attribute supported
                if (downloadAttrSupported) {
                    // Client side extraction
                    a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + this.getCSV().replace(/\n/g, '%0A');
                    a.target = '_blank';
                    a.download = (this.title ? this.title.textStr.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase() : 'chart') + '.csv';
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                    a.remove();

                    // Fall back to server side handling
                } else {
                    Highcharts.post('http://www.highcharts.com/studies/csv-export/csv.php', {
                        csv: this.getCSV()
                    });
                }

            }
        });
    }
}(Highcharts));
```

Comment: Have you any errors in the console? Are you able to recreate your example as live demo ?

Comment: No, I have no errors in the console. I just do not get the list of all options when I inspect element in chrome.